# jQuery Countdown installed. Having trouble displaying multiple countdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Please review my [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/XxZMg/).

I have a jQuery Countdown timer installed. It's nested inside an accordion menu.

There's supposed to be a different timer under each accordion. It only seems to work when I have it under one accordion. Once I placed the code under multiple accordions, it only accepts the data from the last timer.

I'm trying to get one under each. Can you push me in the right direction?

This body script calls the function:

```
//Give the date ---------------------------------
year = 2013; month = 09; day = 27;
//Give the point of time ------------------------
hour= 0; min= 0; sec= 0;

//Standard text ---------------------------------
main_titel= 'Next Start Date - Thursday, October 3, 2013';
//-----------------------------------------------
```

And this script contains the function:

```
function GetCount(){

        dateNow = new Date();                                                            
        amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5;               
        delete dateNow;

        /* time is already past */
        if(amount < 0){
                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span>0<div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span>0<div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span>0<div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span>0<div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;       
        }
        /* date is still good */
        else{
                days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

                amount = Math.floor(amount/1000); /* kill the milliseconds */

                days=Math.floor(amount/86400); /* days */
                amount=amount%86400;

                hours=Math.floor(amount/3600); /* hours */
                amount=amount%3600;

                mins=Math.floor(amount/60); /* minutes */
                amount=amount%60;


                secs=Math.floor(amount); /* seconds */


                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span>" + days +"<div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span>" + hours +"<div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span>" + mins +"<div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span>" + secs +"<div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox').innerHTML=out;


                setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
        }
}

window.onload=function(){GetCount();}
```

**Edit: UPDATE**

So far, I have taken this script here...

```
function GetCount(){

        dateNow = new Date();                                                            
        amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime()+5;               
        delete dateNow;

        /* time is already past */
        if(amount < 0){
                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span>0<div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span>0<div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span>0<div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span>0<div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox1').innerHTML=out;       
        }
        /* date is still good */
        else{
                days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

                amount = Math.floor(amount/1000); /* kill the milliseconds */

                days=Math.floor(amount/86400); /* days */
                amount=amount%86400;

                hours=Math.floor(amount/3600); /* hours */
                amount=amount%3600;

                mins=Math.floor(amount/60); /* minutes */
                amount=amount%60;


                secs=Math.floor(amount); /* seconds */


                out=
                "<div id='days'><span></span>" + days +"<div id='days_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='hours'><span></span>" + hours +"<div id='hours_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='mins'><span></span>" + mins +"<div id='mins_text'></div></div>" + 
                "<div id='secs'><span></span>" + secs +"<div id='secs_text'></div></div>" ;
                document.getElementById('countbox1').innerHTML=out;


                setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
        }
}
```

...and I made four of them total, and then changed days to days2, days3, days4, and did the same with the other variables...

Am I on the right track?

Comment: you are using double id's, which causes your javascript to behave incorrect... Use classes or data attributes in stead

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Can you put a small example in a fiddle... I don't want you to do it all for me, just a little push. Not too good with JS...

Comment: every id can only occure once on an html page. You use ie. the `day` id inside each accordeon, which is invalid. Make sure all your id's are unique first! Validating might help to spot them: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @PeterVR Please see my update above... Does that look right?

Comment: Not really, I had a deeper look at your code, and your javascript needs some (read much) refactoring. I suppose you downloaded this code somewhere. (Where you say 'the body script calls the function' nothing is called, just some global variables are being set, and they are overwritten later in your page) It is not very good code to begin width. Way to much global variables and really not meant to use more then once per page... I think you might be out of your league here, and I really don't have the time to fix all the code. I would suggest you look for a better countdown plugin!

Comment: I have decided to use iframes instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Give the date ---------------------------------
year = 2013; month = 09; day = 27;
//Give the point of time ------------------------
hour= 0; min= 0; sec= 0;

//Standard text ---------------------------------
main_titel= 'Next Start Date - Thursday, October 3, 2013';
//------------------------
```

---

Why is this chunk in the body? They might be executed after your main script.
You should put your scripts in the head, in the order you want them to execute.

Comment: I can't. If you read the question, you'll see that there is a different counter under each section of the accordion. Each counter is assigned a different countdown date. If I do what you're suggesting, then I will only have one counter. I need one for each section. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep. You just have to make sure that when GetCount() is called, those dates are initialized. Also, you shouldn't call GetCount() every second, because you are doing a bunch of unnecessary calculations every second. You should call it once and then have another simple method to count down the time every second.